# Message examples in OpenAPI 3 YAML specification

Tags: json, yaml, openapi

OpenAPI v3 offers using JSON or YAML format.

I prefer using **YAML to create API specifications**. YAML's readability is much better for me as an API designer.

However, sometimes I need to embed a message example whose **type is object**. I usually have the **examples in JSON format**. So I would do the following:

```
examples:
  singlePet:
    summary: Single pet
    description: A request containing a single pet
    value: |
      {
        "pets" : [
          {
            "petType" : "DOG",
            "name" : "Ben"
          }
        ]
      }
```

However, such value is a string, not an object, whereas **OpenAPI expects an object**.

**Do we have any options to embed a JSON as an example value in the YAML specification?**

Currently, I convert the JSON to YAML and embed the YAML:

```
examples:
  singlePet:
    summary: Single pet
    description: A request containing a single pet
    value:
      pets:
        - petType: DOG
          name: Ben
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YAML is a superset of JSON. This means you can use JSON syntax for objects and arrays within a YAML document.

In your first example, you can just remove the `|` after the `value:` to keep the example value as an object.

The following are equivalent:

```yaml
examples:
  singlePet:
    summary: Single pet
    description: A request containing a single pet
    value:
      {
        "pets" : [
          {
            "petType" : "DOG",
            "name" : "Ben"
          }
        ]
      }
```

```yaml
examples:
  singlePet:
    summary: Single pet
    description: A request containing a single pet
    value:
      pets:
      - petType: DOG
        name: Ben
```

Alternatively, you can use [`externalValue`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/#external) to point to an external file containing sample JSON.

```yaml
examples:
  singlePet:
    summary: Single pet
    description: A request containing a single pet
    externalValue: 'https://api.example.com/docs/examples/pet.json'
```

Comment: Thanks, Helen, makes sense and seems to work well!